# Removing dot (".") from the string using python

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a data which looks like this:

- www.r-computer.com
- www.rscompass.com
- www.italy.it
  and so.

I have written a script which looks like this:

```
data['website']=data['Website address'].str.split('www.').str[1]
data['website']=data['website'].str.split('.com').str[0]
```

This basically first removes the "www" and then the second code was intended to remove the ".com" from the string.
The result I should be getting for the 1st and 2nd data point should be:

- r-computer
- rscompass

But instead I am getting is "r". So i think Python is not interpreting "." as dot, but any character before "com".

I would like to know how to remove phrases such as ".ru" , ".com", ".it" etc. Kindly help.

Comment: String acessor `str.split()` uses regex (I think), so you want to escape the wildcat with `'\.com'` or `'www\.'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re


def get_domain(s):
    return re.sub("^www\.(.+)\.[^\.]+$", "\\1", s)

print(get_domain("www.r-computer.com"))   # r-computer
```

(untested)
Return both sitename and .com .org etc. Return None if there is no match

```
import re


def get_domain(s):
    ret = re.findall("^www\.(.+)\.([^\.]+)$", s)
    return ret[0] if ret else (None, None)


# example
a, b = get_domain("www.italy.it")

if a and b:
    print(a)  # italy
    print(b)  # it
```

Comment: Could you also explain how is this working ? Like how do Implement this in other examples such as taking ".it" our of italy.it. 
Thank you.

Comment: It looks for: 1. 'www.' in the beginning of the line  2. as many characters as possible in the end of the line that are not dot (.)  3. any characters inbetween 1 and 2, and a dot. Then it returns 3. In other words: [start of line]www.[RETURN THIS].[no dots][end of line]

Comment: Great! thank you so much. Also, any Idea about how to retrieve the domain? like .it, .org, .com etc

Answer (score 0):

For the examples provided, this will work:

```
data['website']=data['website'].split('.')[1]
```

What this does is get the text between the first and second `'.'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
yourstring.translate({ord('.'):None})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).